# Using a WP Query for a carousel slider

Tags: wordpress, slider, carousel

I made a Custom Field in my Posts to which Trip a single Post is depending. So, for example, I made a road trip and for every city, there is a post.

Now, after collecting all written posts of a single trip into one wp query I want to display them in a kind of carousel so the user can see which other cities I traveled to in my trip.

Any suggestions what to use here? I am really stuck for around a week or so.

Btw I am not the best coder but I do my very best =)

Thanks and Cheers
Stefan

Answer (score 0):

Hope it helps...

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <!-- Getting all the cities of the travel -->
    <?php $collection_of_cities_by_travel = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'city_visited', false ); ?>
    <?php if( $collection_of_cities_by_travel ) : ?>
        <ul class="slick-slider"> <!-- http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ 100% recomended-->
        <?php foreach ( $collection_of_cities_by_travel as $city ): $city_post = get_the_post( $city ); ?>
            <!-- Print the detail of every single city (post) in the travel -->
            <li class="slide">
                <a href="<?php echo get_the_permalink( $city_post->ID ); ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $city_post->ID, 'post-thumbnail' ); ?>
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $city_post->ID ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```